# Getting "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied" when hitting the URL without "www" prefix

Tags: active-directory, domain, url, isa-server

I'm facing problem in my domain area. when i hit for example http://abc.com then I'm not able to access the site which are hosted on my domain. It gives the below error

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

But when I hit http://www.abc.com then I'm able to access the sites under my domain. so please let me know where I'm doing mistake in my configuration.

note: I'm using ISA server as a proxy server for my domain.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. try and ping both the domain.. i.e without www and with www. See if they resolves to same IP address.
2. Check your web server configuration files.
3. observe the output of curl -I        with www and wihtout www

Comment: when I ping with www it resolve some other IP address but when without www I'm getting the Ip of my local domain IP

Comment: Okay, you have to make changes to the DNS of your domain.  Add an A record as @ and enter the IP address as value.   OR you can do this in your windows machine. Edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc/hosts file and add your domain name here with or without www and enter the IP address where your site is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have www record.  Create CNAME record with `www` pointing to the `abc.com.`